# Master list of all Tkinter Events?

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I'm searching for a master list of all Tkinter `events`. I've been googling for such a list all all morning without success. Any references for such a list would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such list as far as I know. There is a list of most events on the bind man page, but each widget can itself issue events unique to that widget (eg: `<<ListboxSelect>>`). Those are documented on the man page for each widget.

Comment: Great idea to check out the bind man page. Would you have a link for such a page? Googling on 'tkinter bind man page', 'tkinter bind documentation', etc. come up empty.

Comment: Tkinter is just a thin wrapper around tcl/tk, so the tcl/tk man pages are very useful. You just have to make some small mental adjustments (eg: `widget.grid(...)` versus `grid $widget ...` The official tcl/tk man pages are at http://www.tcl.tk/man

Answer (score 8):

We had this discussion on the tkinter mailing list, and found the following:

- [Event Types, as listed in the Tk documentation.](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm#M7)

  - For example a KeyPress `<Control-m>` for tk.Text
- Virtual events are not listed there. For virtual events, check individual widget help pages.

  - For example `<<Undo>>` for tk.Text

Summarized in the wiki: [tkinter:Events](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/Events)

Answer (score 4):

I found a more complete listing of known events, including some marked as "Undocumented", in Python's own tkinter module.  Start here, and scroll down to `class EventType`:
[https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/**init**.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py)

Whether that's the penultimate list or not....who knows.  It seems Tk/Tkinter documentation is spread fairly thinly, like vegemite on toast, across the entirety of the Internet.