# List of Sequences Available for Each TKinter Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Is there a reference site that contains, for each Tkinter widget, a list of all available sequences for binding?

For example, I can bind a callback to a TreeView with this code:

```
tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", selection_changed)
```

However, I can't seem to find a good resource that will list all possible events to which a callback can be assigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code to get events for some widget (except virtual events):

```
from itertools import chain
def get_events(widget):
    return set(chain.from_iterable(widget.bind_class(cls) for cls in widget.bindtags()))

root = Tk()
a = get_events(Button())
print(a)
root.destroy()

>>> {'<KeyRelease-Alt_R>', '<Enter>', '<Key-space>', '<Button-1>', '<Key-Alt_R>', '<KeyRelease-F10>', '<<PrevWindow>>', '<Alt-Key>', '<Alt-KeyRelease>', '<ButtonRelease-1>', '<Leave>', '<KeyRelease-Alt_L>', '<Key-Alt_L>', '<Key-F10>', '<Key-Tab>'}
```

And links: [Master list of all Tkinter Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172659/python-tkinter-master-list-of-all-tkinter-events)

Comment: +1: It's a surprisingly tricky problem; Tk has a complex event model inside (that's grown with supporting a very wide range of apps). The actual bindings are also platform-specific (or worse, if you do something silly like turning on traditional Motif compatibility mode; don't do that). Also, be aware that some widgets (especially canvases) can have bindings on individual elements inside.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I think that, with all of Tkinter's quirks, it might be best for me to switch to wxPython.