# Tkinter REALLY ALL Complete Event List

Tags: python, tkinter

I have already found the incomplete helps on this and other sites.
Maybe I need to iterate what i mean. If you have a for example `'<Motion>'`.Event and you print its `.type`, you get:

```
print(mot_event.type)
>>>6
```

You get this for all the events, but **nowhere** a **complete** list for **all the numbers**. I found so far:

- 2: "KeyPress",
- 3: "KeyRelease",
- 4: "ButtonPress",
- 5: "ButtonRelease",
- 6: "Motion",
- 7: "Enter",
- 8: "Leave",
- 9: "FocusIn",
- 10: "FocusOut",
- 12: "Expose",
- 15: "Visibility",
- 17: "Destroy",
- 18: "Unmap",
- 19: "Map",
- 21: "Reparent",
- 22: "Configure",
- 24: "Gravity",
- 26: "Circulate",
- 28: "Property",
- 32: "Colormap",
- 36: "Activate",
- 37: "Deactivate",
- 38: "MouseWheel"

What is the event for `.type` for 1, 11, 13, 14, 16, 20, 23, .... 39-x

Is there a function that converts 2 to `'<KeyPress>'`?

Or is this just sick joke of tkinter team? I have to know!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Master list of all Tkinter Events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172659/master-list-of-all-tkinter-events)

Comment: The numbers might well be platform-dependent.  Ignore them; only the names are important.

Comment: As mentioned at [Listings of Events in tkinter](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/Events) these event type numbers are derived from X windows. You can see the original codes in [X11/X.h](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.3.0/gLSB/gLSB/libx11-ddefs.html)

Comment: It looks like Tkinter currently includes a fairly complete Event Type list in its main module.  Scroll down to the `class EventType` definition:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no function that converts `2` to `<KeyPress>`. And no, it's not a sick joke by the tkinter team. That sort of information simply isn't necessary, or particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bryan Oakley,

but for educational or debugging purposes, this may help:

```
from tkinter import EventType
def eventTypeForId(id):
    return [e for e, v in EventType.__members__.items() if v == str(id)][0]
```

with this,

```
eventTypeForId(2)
```

results in

```
'KeyPress'
```